# Cannot convert from string to Object(animal)

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class VetShop
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Animal[] Clients = new Animal[73];
  //File ClientInfo = new File("C:/Users/William/Desktop/HomeWork5/program5.txt");
  inputData(Clients);
  SortData(Clients);
  ReportData(Clients);
 }

 public static void inputData(Animal[] client)throws InputMismatchException
 {
  //reading
  File ClientInfo = new File("C:/Users/William/Desktop/HomeWork5/program5.txt");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(ClientInfo);
  //Animal X = new Animal(
  while(input.hasNext())
  {
   for(int i = 1; i <=client.length ;i++)
   {

   client[i]= input.nextLine();   //Problem is here
   //System.out.println(numbers[j]);

   }
  }

 }


 public static void SortData(Animal[] clients)
 {
  //Not HERE YET
 }

 public static void ReportData(Animal[] clients)
 {
  //Not HERE YET
 }
}
```

this is the text file we need to use

hopper 2003 555 Kangaroo 2

kitty 2009 44 Cat 4

Spot 2005 333 Dog 4

Johnny 2008 111 Cat 4

Dan 2015 433 Dog 4

Striper 2011 432 Sckunk 4

Edward 1995 630 Horse 4

casper 1998 88 Snake Cold-Blooded

Boots 2005 987 Horse 4

Ryan 2014 21 fish Cold-Blooded

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What is the problem? An exception, a compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
client[i]= input.nextLine();   //Problem is here
```

as

```
client[i] = new Animal();
String line = input.nextLine();
```

This is because `input.nextLine()` returns a String, not an Animal.

And now, parse `line` and split it in the fields it has.  For example:

```
 hopper 2003 555 Kangaroo 2
```

has 5 fields.

Also, please, change the name of the variable 'client' to 'animals'.

Comment: how do I parse the line and split it.

Comment: line.split(" ") or something similar.  See the java documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String).

Comment: Perhaps the Scanner class has some method to do this job.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot convert a String to an Animal as they are two different types of objects. What you can possibly do is create a `public static Animal parse(String string)` method in the Animal class which will take a String and return a parsed Animal object that you can then add to the array. Then you may call it in the following way:

```
client[i] = Animal.parse(input.nextLine());
```

In the parse method, you can create a new Animal, split the String and set appropriate fields in the Animal object that you just created and finally, return that newly created Animal object.

Comment: How do you split the string

Comment: `String[] stringArray = string.split(" ");`
This code will split the string at every space

Comment: How do I split a single string line.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-split-a-string/)

Comment: How do I store "Dan 2015 433 Dog 4" into an array and after its in the array how do I split it

Comment: Try this with a simple small Java program. Try and mess around with splitting strings and parsing in Java and if you have any questions, then ask here.